# Django get a foreign key from a foreign key in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to get a foreign key of a foreign key in 1 query but I can't make it work

Models

```
class Storage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                            null=False,
                            blank=False,
                            unique=True)

class Freezer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                            null=False,
                            blank=False,
                            unique=True)
    storage = models.ForeignKey(Storage,
                                models.CASCADE,
                                blank=True,
                                null=True,
                                related_name='freezer')

class Rack(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                            null=False,
                            blank=False,
                            unique=True)
    freezer = models.ForeignKey(Freezer,
                                models.CASCADE,
                                blank=True,
                                null=True,
                                related_name='rack')
```

Code

This works when I get all the freezers

```
display_text = ", ".join([
    "<a href={}>{}</a>".format(
        reverse(
            'admin:{}_{}_change'.format("admin",
                                        "freezer"),
            args=(items.pk, )), items)
    for items in obj.freezer.all()
])
if display_text:
    return mark_safe(display_text)
```

But I cannot get the rack on this query

```
display_text = ", ".join([
    "<a href={}>{}</a>".format(
        reverse(
            'admin:{}_{}_change'.format("admin",
                                        "rack"),
            args=(items.pk, )), items)
    for items in obj.freezer.rack.all()
])
if display_text:
    return mark_safe(display_text)
```

Any suggestions sorry I'm new?

Comment: Show us your views.py, please

Comment: @HigorRossato this has nothing to do with views, this is the admin changelist.

Comment: Oh, sorry. My bad, thanks for pointing that our @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 0):

With this sort of calculation you should start from the class you need, ie Rack.

```
... for items in Rack.objects.filter(freezer__storage=obj)
```

(Note, you've made things much more confusing than they need to be by setting the related_names to the singular "rack" and "freezer". If you must set them at all, which I don't recommend, you should at least use plural names.)